# Doxygen - parse everything regardless of preprocessor directive

Tags: c++, c, doxygen, preprocessor

I have a single header C/C++ library which contains different inline functions whether the header is included from C or C++.

```
#ifndef __cplusplus
  // C stuff
#else
  // C++ stuff
#endif
```

The problem is that doxygen always parses just one of the two paths depending on whether I predefine __cplusplus myself or not. Entirely disabling preprocessing is no option either as I have other macros I'd like to keep in the documentation.

Is there any sane way to generate documentation for the C and the C++ part of the header?

Comment: Are those functions different versions of same functions (same interface), or completely different functions with different names?

Comment: Only possibility you have is to wrap the `#ifndef __cplusplus`, `#else` `#endif` in an `#ifdef DOXYGEN_ENABLED` and define DOXYGEN_ENABLED in your Doxyfile.

Comment: @user463035818 referencing the docs you did is not the best as that is version  1.3.5 (from 2003) better is to reference http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/preprocessing.html

Comment: @user694733 I hope so as otherwise my solution won't work either.

Comment: @albert it was the first I found. i'll delete mine...

Comment: Some of the functions are identical but the C++ interface is way richer. I simply didn't want to pollute global namespace while still offering some support for C users...
And yes, of course I've red the docs first but so far I couldn't come up with a solution which doesn't either discard the C/C++ part or other macros inside the header. I guess if nothing else works one could still preprocess the header and generate a temporary file to parse for doxygen.